# Create line chart with column titles on X axis

Tags: r

I want to create a line chart for a df with the following structure:

[image: Example df]

What I want the line chart to show is each contribution of the Participants per column. Meaning on the X-axis should be the column names of T1a_PlantTree_1 - T1a_PlantTree_6 and on the Y-axis the average contribution of all participants (In the df as PROLIFIC_PID)

The Y-axis can be in 0,20,40,60,80,100 steps but doesn't have to.

Resulting from this should be a diagram with a single line for the average contribution of each column that contains T1a_PlantTree_ in its name.

I'm new to R and still struggle with easy tasks. Thanks a lot for any help I get, it's appreciated!

I have tried the following code, but it resulted in 0 observations...
[image: Code]

Further result of: 
[> dput(head(Treatment1a))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYqYx.png)

Best,
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~Px,~T1a_PlantTree_1,~T1a_PlantTree_2,~T1a_PlantTree_3,~T1a_PlantTree_4,~T1a_PlantTree_5,
                                       "P1" , 15 , 40 , 20 , 60 , 58,
                                       "P2" , 15 , 40 , 20 , 60 , 58,
                                       "P3" , 15 , 40 , 20 , 60 , 58,
                                       "P4" , 15 , 40 , 20 , 60 , 58
  )

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Px, names_to = "Condition", values_to = "values") %>% 
  group_by(Condition) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mean_contribution = mean(values)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Condition, y = mean_contribution, group = 1)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dominik, I have problems to understand your example. Is it specific to the values you have written in red because in my original df I have way more rows and of course varying values between 0 and 100. I need a general solution which is not specific to the numbers in the rows. Sorry if I get something wrong

Comment: Ah ok sorry I thought you only had those 5 specific values between 0 and 100. Is the updated answer closer to what you want to do?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion @Dominik, I have now updated the question with a specific example of my df (name Treatment1a) so that it should be more understanding.

Comment: Ah you want the average per condition to be plotted, not the contribution of each individual? The updated answer plots the average contribution per condition (average over all participants).

Comment: Thanks, that looks way better! How can I apply the plot to take all the information from the df and not from the written numbers in your code?

Comment: You should only have to replace `-Px` with `-PROLIFIC_PID` and `df` with the name of your data frame. Please consider accepting the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Or if you have more columns (what you probably have) use `T1a_PlantTree_1:T1a_PlantTree_6` instead of `-Px`

Comment: Got that one and works fine. However, I cannot see any results in the plot.
In the updated comment you provided, there is still the example matrix included (e.g. "P1" , 15 , 40 , 20 , 60 , 58,). How can I make it that it relies on all the data within the df without having to write down each row in the code?

Comment: You can ignore the data in my answer. This is just to make it reproducible. Skip that part and just use the name of your dataframe instead of `df` at the beginning of the pipe.

Comment: I think it did that. I have now updated my questions again so that you can see what I tried. When I skip the data in your answer, I get 0 observations in my df. Sorry if I'm getting something wrong here.

Comment: Can you post the result of `dput(head(Treatment1a))`?

Comment: The result is added to my question. Any ideas?

Comment: Well `Treatment1a` is empty. Delete the `tibble::tribble(...)` command (line 191-194) and let the whole script run again.

Comment: No worries, nothing to do with you, R is not easy in the beginning. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.